# Exception loading EMF file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

When I try to load an EMF file I get the following error:

> Exception thrown:
>   org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: Package
>   with uri 'blah/blah' not found. (file:/C:/Temp/OPDiag1/blah1.opmeta,
>   2, 124)

The code I am using to try and load:

```
opmetaFactory.eINSTANCE.eClass();
Resource opmmResource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI(uri));
try {
  opmmResource.load(null);
  opd = (OPMetaModelDiagram) opmmResource.getContents().get(0);
} catch(final IOException e) { 
  // log
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the package of the metamodel in the package registry first:

```
resourceSet.getPackageRegistry().put(BlahPackage.eNS_URI, BlahPackage.eINSTANCE);
```

For an UML model for example it would be "UMLPackage.eNS_URI" etc. In your case, I suppose it must something like "OpmetaPackage.eNS_URI" and "OpmetaPackage.eINSTANCE".